# How should a disjoint union wrapper be structured for refinement to work?

Tags: flowtype

[On the Flowtype "Try" site](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AeQHY4C8oA3utgFygBEBWNAvgNyqY4Aq8soJ571Gl1hNWFHADlYAE2J5CoAD6hhrZAGNoAQwDOO0ADFYsADwTqU2QD4yiUKHwysFtffWx8OlACcArupRYbwAKfAsASlt7exQACwBLHQA6R1leB1Z7RkRsjQ8vUEhjS2dDYzMnGxJCeDLYYP4qWnomcNZ4yFBgotgSlKck8V4iEjpCGkjSO1B3TxRC43pqI1N6KoXep1ZGIA)

```
// @flow

type One = {type: "One"};
type Two = {type: "Two"};
type Node = One | Two;


class Foo<N: Node> {
  node: N;

  constructor(n: N) {
    this.node = n;
  }
}

const fooNode: Foo<Node> = new Foo({type: "One"});
if (fooNode.node.type === "One") {
  const fooOne: Foo<One> = fooNode;
}
```

the `if` type check is not enough to refine the type, if I understand right, because the type is not guaranteed to be constant.

Since I want to avoid the possibility of this being an X/Y problem, the usecase I'm playing with at the moment is searching from a given node with a `.find` method that would return the refined type, e.g. using

```
  parent(): Foo<N> | null {
    // ...
    return null;
  }

  find<U: Node>(callback: (foo: Foo<N>) => Foo<U> | null): Foo<U> | null {
    let p = this;
    do {
      const result = callback(p);
      if (result) return result;

      p = p.parent();
    } while (p);

    return null;
  }
```

with

```
const f: Foo<Node> = new Foo({type: "One"});

const result: Foo<Two>|null = f.find((p) => p.node.type === "Two" ? p : null);
```

which would allow me to return the refined type at the while searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the type annotation on this line:

```
const fooNode: Foo<Node> = new Foo({type: "One"});
```

By explicitly using `Foo<Node>` you're preventing the refinement from happening. You can use `Foo<*>` to make the inference work correctly.

Here's an example:
https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AeQHY4C8oA3qOtgFygBEBWtoAvgNyqY4Aq8soJ5Slhq0esJmw7ZQAOVgATYnkKgAPqDHtEAY2gBDAM4HQAMViwAPDJpzFAPjKJQofAuGytz7bHwGUAJwBXbRRYfwAKfBsASkdnZxQACwBLAwA6V0V+F3ZnZkR85G9fFFBIc1t3M0sAKgcSQnhTc3DSIREGWmZo9nDy2EqaaosGOx7EPoq3IfMLMTHWUBBQLH9-MKA

Comment: Interesting. I was setting the type explicitly because in a normal case I'd probably expect the `fooNode` logic to be in a function with that value coming from a function argument. Is this a case where I should make the function argument `fooNode: Foo<*>`?

Comment: probably, or just have a generic type N (with a type bound :Node) on the function too

Comment: Both examples are meaningless. In the first one there is no refinement at all, you can just remove the `if`. The second one simply breaks Flow and `f` ends up being `any`

Comment: @vkurchatkin you're absolutely right, I rushed too much while working with the examples. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems. `Foo` is invariant, so you will never be able to refine it: it doesn't have any known subtypes other than itself.

On the other hand, even if `Foo` was covariant, it wouldn't work. You simply can't refine a generic class.

The only practical option is to unwrap, refine, and wrap again.

Comment: I'm accepting the other answer since it was a bit more of a shove in the right direction, but both were super helpful, thanks a ton.